# Playing Audio files with GTK and c++

Tags: c++, gtk, audio-player

i'm currently building a very simple music player with the gtk+ and c++ code but now i am unable to figure out how to open and play the audio file using C++ code.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
// simple music player to practice gtk and c++//

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *playButton;
GtkWidget *fileButton;
GtkWidget *frame;
GtkWidget *Dialog;


window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);

frame = gtk_fixed_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

playButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Play");
gtk_widget_set_size_request(playButton,80,40);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame),playButton,40,330);

fileButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Open");
gtk_widget_set_size_request(fileButton,80,40);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame),fileButton,40,260);

gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();

return 0;
}
```

so as you can see i have created the open button to select your files and i know the dialog code;

```
GtkWidget *dialog;

dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("OpenFile",parent_window,GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT, NULL);

if (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
    char *filename;

    filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog));
    open_file (filename);
   g_free (filename);
 }

gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
```

but my problem is i do not know how to place the code, i should more than likely create a function and set a callback to that function when the open buttot is clicked. right?   And then the second problem coes no matter how hard i search i can't seem to find how to play the audio file, thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using external libraries [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) makes it incredibly easy to play Audio files in a variety of formats. Here is an example of how to play a .wav audio file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_acodec.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;
   ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *sample=NULL;

   if(!al_init()){
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   if(!al_install_audio()){
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize audio!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   if(!al_init_acodec_addon()){
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize audio codecs!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   if (!al_reserve_samples(1)){
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to reserve samples!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   sample = al_load_sample( "footstep.wav" );

   if (!sample){
      printf( "Audio clip sample not loaded!\n" ); 
      return -1;
   }

   display = al_create_display(640, 480);

   if(!display){
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   /* Loop the sample until the display closes. */
   al_play_sample(sample, 1.0, 0.0,1.0,ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_LOOP,NULL);

   al_rest(10.0);

   al_destroy_display(display);
   al_destroy_sample(sample);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if we are not allowed to use external libraries? Also, is there any way to play sounds without needing an external file?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm incredibly late, but here's my proposal: Use the Gtk4 MediaStream API with Gtk::MediaFile.

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create();
    Gtk::Window w;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::MediaFile> mediafile = Gtk::MediaFile::create_for_filename("example.ogg");
    mediafile->play();
    return app->make_window_and_run<MyWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example `pkg-config gtkmm-4.0 --libs --cflags`
```